# How to add GIF images to Asset Catalog in XCode5

Tags: ios, xcode5, asset-catalog

Does any one know how to add GIF image files to an Asset Catalog in XCode5?

Comment: Animated GIF like image.gif won't animate with `iOS` SDK.

Comment: Showing the animated GIF, I'm handling in code. I'm basically migrating my old code to new version and moved all images to assets but a few gif's I have can't be added

Comment: @XCodeMonkey this question is in not way a duplicate of the one you marked. I'm talking about the new feature added in XCODE 5 for managing assets. Please read before making assumptions

Answer (score 8):

Go to your Images.xcassets folder and create a folder named MyGifAnimation.xcassets, then put your MyGifAnimation@2x.gif and MyGifAnimation.gif files in it. After that, create a Contents.json file. Open that with your favorite text editor and write the following in it:

```
{
    "images": [{
        "idiom": "universal",
        "scale": "1x",
        "filename": "MyGifAnimation.gif"
    }, {
        "idiom": "universal",
        "scale": "2x",
        "filename": "MyGifAnimation@2x.gif"
    }],
    "info": {
        "version": 1,
        "author": "xcode"
    }
}
```

You'll have to handle the animation yourself as loading it directly to a UIImageView won't result in an animated gif.

Comment: Like @Joey, I could not get this to work in modern Xcode (7.2.1). The `.xcassets` editor displays the manually-created `.imageset` correctly, but calling `imageNamed:` on it returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know guys, I'll check this issue and update my answer soon. This is a hacky way so I can understand it not working anymore.

Comment: @BarışŞencan It doesn't look that hacky; can't check right now the exact details but it looks pretty much like the `Contents.json` files that Xcode typically generates...