# How do i make my spriteNode textures universal?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, texture-atlas

I've been working on a universal game with SpriteKit, and I have my images in .gif I have the normal definition the @2x and the  @3x, I need to know how to create an atlas and how to change between atlases when the device is bigger or smaller and which of the definitions (@2x, @3x) is for what device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode will automatically create an atlas for you. Use the Images.xcassets to store your images at @1x, @2x & @3x. Xcode will auto pick the appropriate image resolution for you.

You need to read Apple's [Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) docs.

Comment: @reojased- Cassettes ?

Comment: yes I've tried it but apparently it does not accept them

Comment: @reojased- I believe PNG is the default format for this but you can take a look at this post if you prefer to keep it in GIF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462747/how-to-add-gif-images-to-asset-catalog-in-xcode5

Comment: thank you, finally a good answer, that solves my problems with images.xcassets